# How to use the CKFinder Javascript api?

Tags: javascript, ckfinder

Funny question, but i honestly can't acces (for example) the `CKFinder.dataTypes.Folder`: http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.dataTypes.Folder.html.

I have downloaded the CKFinder 2.x demo for asp.net to try the utility out and the only thing intellisense is giving me access to is the window.CKFinder object and some of its methods, but nothing else. I couldn't find `Folder` in ckfinder.js either.

Comment: You may be better off at CKEditor's support resources? This sounds very specialized. Anyway, retagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.dataTypes.Folder.html#constructor) you may not be able to access it directly, instead you should call any ***Folder API function*** once CKFinder object has been loaded.

> Note: the **CKFinder.dataTypes** namespace is not directly accessible
>   (CKFinder.dataTypes is undefined). Data types are used internally by
>   CKFinder and returned by many functions, like
>   CKFinderAPI#getSelectedFolder.

The following example is an initialization in javascript of the CKFinder component which shows how to access the Folder datatype.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.basePath = '/js/ckfinder/'; // The path for the installation of CKFinder (default = "/ckfinder/").
    // Setting custom width and user language.
    finder.width = '99%';
    finder.defaultLanguage = 'es';
    finder.language = 'es';

    finder.removePlugins = 'basket';
    //finder.selectActionFunction = showFileInfo;
    //finder.resourceType = 'Images';
    //finder.tabIndex = 1;
    //finder.startupPath = "Images:/";

    finder.callback = function( api ) 
    {
        api.openMsgDialog( "", "Almost ready to go!" );
        api.hideTool( "f2" );//hide flash folder
        api.openFolder('Images', '/');
        var folder = api.getSelectedFolder();
        //console.debug(folder);
        folder.createNewFolder( 'New Folder' );
        //api.setUiColor('white');
    };
    var api = (finder).create();

    //console.debug(api);
    //api.openMsgDialog("Sample title","Sample message."); //doesnt work here, CKFinder still not loaded.
</script>
```

Comment: Also when testing some changes, make sure you close the browser and opening it again. I have seen a lot of cache and refresh configuration problems with CKFinder.