# Open ckFinder 2.3 without ckeditor

Tags: ckfinder

I want to browse the folder that used for ckFinder without the ckEditor. I followed the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463025/how-to-use-the-ckfinder-javascript-api), and also the [API](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.html), but seems like the ckFinder keeps creating new folder instead of browsing to current folder.

If I browse to the `ckfinder.html` in a new tab or new window, I'll get system error popup.

How can I use ckFinder without the ckEditor? Or any recommended file manager?

EDIT(1):

I found another free file manager [[HERE]](http://test.albertoperipolli.com/filemanager4tinymce/). But still hoping for any solution for the ckFinder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckfinder.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function BrowseServer()
{
var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.basePath = '../';
    finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
    finder.popup();
}
function SetFileField( fileUrl )
{
    document.getElementById( 'xFilePath' ).value = fileUrl;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="xFilePath" name="FilePath" type="text" size="60" />
<input type="button" value="Browse Server" onclick="BrowseServer();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

special input integration for CKFinder 3

http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_integration

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>CKFinder 3</title>
     <script src="/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script>
         function openPopup() {
             CKFinder.popup( {
                 chooseFiles: true,
                 onInit: function( finder ) {
                     finder.on( 'files:choose', function( evt ) {
                         var file = evt.data.files.first();
                         document.getElementById( 'url' ).value = file.getUrl();
                     } );
                     finder.on( 'file:choose:resizedImage', function( evt ) {
                         document.getElementById( 'url' ).value = evt.data.resizedUrl;
                     } );
                 }
             } );
         }
     </script>
     <input type="text" size="48" name="url" id="url" />
     <button type="button" onclick="openPopup()">Select file</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```